# ajax perform only once in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want rendering the table using Ajax. Table in div. I write text into textbox , click the button and return the table with new text. Ajax perform only once. I clicked the button and first it works fine, the text is adding into tabel, but then it didn't work. I change the type to button and writing jquery, it is not working.Please help me.

```
<div id="render">
 <table>table here</table>
 </div>
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateTask", "Admin", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "render", HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new{id = "myForm"}))
                      {
                   @Html.TextBox("Text")
                   @Html.Hidden("ID", item.ID)
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success" />
                            }


 public ActionResult CreateTask(int ID, string text)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        Project project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == ID);
        Tasking task = new Tasking { Name = text, Status = false };
        project.Tasks.Add(task);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index", this.db.Projects.ToList());
        return PartialView("_PartiaV", db.Projects.ToList());
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var formdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Admin/CreateTask",
                data: formdata,
                success: function () {

                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Your code should work fine. You do not need the button click event handler as you are already using an ajax form. I just copied and pasted your code and it worked (I was able to add more than one time)

Comment: thanks for answering. i will check it again.

Comment: Having both `Ajax.BeginForm()` and `$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {` to submit you form makes no sense (and you not cancelling the ajax call made by `Ajax.BeginForm()` so your making 2 ajax calls to post the data twice). And since your replacing the button with `id="btnSubmit"` then `$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {` will not work the 2nd time (refer [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to understand. And note also `ModelState.Clear();` makes no sense and the you do not do anything with the partial view in the `success` callback